# change datetime from mysql to string format on php

Tags: php, mysql

I need help converting  my datetime format to string format on my php page

for example if i have this date format: 2013-03-26 20:18:55

I would like it to be displayed on my page as: March 26,2013 20:18:55.

this is my query which gets values from mysql

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo 
                        'Date:' . $row['postDate'] . 
                        '</br>Posted by: ' . $row['firstName'] . 
                        '</br>Post :' . $row['post']. 
                        '<br/> <p>';}
mysqli_close($db);
```

note that my date type of my 'postDate' is datetime

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date('F d, Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate']));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$datetime = new DateTime($row['postDate']);
$datetime->format('F d, Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: I believe you mean `new dateTime`, not `new $dateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array with names of months January, February... and when you fetch your data just split your date with "-" and then check the month number..for example if you have 02 then display February. You can use a switch case for checking.

Comment: Do you really think this is better then the solutions already posted?

Comment: The problem is because I'dont seen your solution when I'm writing my answer.

Comment: But one question, if you try to display a name of month in language which is not in PHP documentation, for example if for January you want to display "Januar".. Do you think that your solution is useful ?

Answer (score 0):

here's two options:

You can change your query to format the date to the format you want
[See DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

or use PHP's strtotime() and date() funcs

```
date('F j,Y, H:i:s',strtotime($row['postDate']))
```